# React js update prop child, not changing the state of the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props, react-component

[image]

As you can see from the image I have a page where,
the part of the drawer and the dark mode change is found on the parent page.

Where the word `Page1` and the `input field` appear, in the child page.

When the theme is changed, then switched to dark mode, a prop with the `darkState` state is passed from parent to child.

As you can see from the image if I have an input field in which I am writing, so with some text, then I switch to `dark mode` or I open the `drawer`.

The component updates everything, losing all its internal state.

I thought about using `useMemo`, but I don't know where I should use it.

Can you give me a hand?

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-sara-dru7w?file=/src/page/Page1.js

App.js

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Switch, Route, Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  AppBar,
  CssBaseline,
  Drawer,
  Hidden,
  IconButton,
  List,
  ListItem,
  ListItemIcon,
  ListItemText,
  Toolbar,
  Chip
} from "@material-ui/core";
import { GTranslate, Menu } from "@material-ui/icons";
import {
  makeStyles,
  useTheme,
  createMuiTheme,
  ThemeProvider
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { blue, grey } from "@material-ui/core/colors";
import DarkModeToggle from "react-dark-mode-toggle";
import { Page1, Page2, Error } from "./page";
import "./styles/main.css";
import "./App.css";

const drawerWidth = 240;

function App(props) {
  const { wind } = props;
  const container = wind !== undefined ? () => wind().document.body : undefined;
  const prefersDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;
  const localDark = localStorage.getItem("dark");
  const isDark = localDark === null ? prefersDark : localDark === "true";

  let location = useLocation();
  let pathname = location.pathname.replace("/", "");
  if (pathname === "") pathname = "page1";

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    mobileOpen: false,
    darkState: isDark,
    repo: []
  });
  const { mobileOpen, darkState } = state;

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      display: "flex"
    },
    drawer: {
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        flexShrink: 0
      }
    },
    appBar: {
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        marginLeft: drawerWidth
      }
    },
    menuButton: {
      marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
      [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
        display: "none"
      },
      backgroundColor: darkState ? grey[900] : blue[500]
    },
    // necessary for content to be below app bar
    toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
    drawerPaper: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      color: "#ffffff",
      backgroundColor: darkState ? grey[900] : blue[500]
    },
    content: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      padding: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  }));

  const palletType = darkState ? "dark" : "light";
  const mainPrimaryColor = darkState ? grey[900] : blue[500];
  const mainSecondaryColor = darkState ? grey[800] : blue[300];
  const darkTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: palletType,
      primary: {
        main: mainPrimaryColor
      },
      secondary: {
        main: mainSecondaryColor
      }
    }
  });

  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const handleDrawerToggle = () =>
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, mobileOpen: !mobileOpen }));
  const changePage = (page) => setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, page }));
  const handleThemeChange = React.useCallback(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("dark", !darkState);
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, darkState: !prev.darkState }));
  }, []);

  const menu = [
    { title: "Page1", path: "page1", icon: <GTranslate /> },
    { title: "Page2", path: "page2", icon: <GTranslate /> }
  ];

  const routeObj = [
    { path: "/", obj: <Page1 darkState={darkState} /> },
    { path: "page1", obj: <Page1 darkState={darkState} /> },
    { path: "page2", obj: <Page2 darkState={darkState} /> }
  ];

  const drawer = (
    <div className="mt-32">
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <List>
        {menu.map(({ title, path, icon, badge }, index) => (
          <Link to={`/${path}`} key={title}>
            <ListItem button key={title} onClick={() => changePage(path)}>
              <ListItemIcon
                style={{ color: path === pathname ? "#ffffff" : "#ffffff80" }}
              >
                {icon}
              </ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText
                primary={<span className="font-bold">{title}</span>}
                style={{ color: path === pathname ? "#ffffff" : "#ffffff80" }}
              />
              {badge && (
                <Chip
                  label={badge}
                  size="small"
                  color="secondary"
                  className="font-bold"
                  style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}
                />
              )}
            </ListItem>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={darkTheme}>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <AppBar
          position="fixed"
          className={classes.appBar}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: darkState ? "#303030" : grey[50],
            boxShadow: "none"
          }}
        >
          <Toolbar className={"shadow-none"}>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              edge="start"
              onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
              className={classes.menuButton}
            >
              <Menu />
            </IconButton>
            <div className="ml-auto text-right flex">
              <DarkModeToggle
                onChange={handleThemeChange}
                checked={darkState}
                size={60}
              />
            </div>
          </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>

        <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
          {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
          <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
            <Drawer
              container={container}
              variant="temporary"
              anchor={theme.direction === "rtl" ? "right" : "left"}
              open={mobileOpen}
              onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper
              }}
              ModalProps={{
                keepMounted: true // Better open performance on mobile.
              }}
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
          <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
            <Drawer
              classes={{
                paper: classes.drawerPaper
              }}
              variant="permanent"
              open
            >
              {drawer}
            </Drawer>
          </Hidden>
        </nav>
        <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar} />
          <Switch>
            {routeObj.map(({ path, obj }, key) => (
              <Route exact path={`/${path}`} component={() => obj} key={key} />
            ))}
            <Route component={() => <Error darkState={darkState} />} />
          </Switch>
        </main>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

App.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
   * You won't need it on your project.
   */
  wind: PropTypes.func
};

export default App;
```

Page1.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { TextField, makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import { className } from "../function";
import "../styles/main.css";

export default function Page1({ darkState }) {
  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    title: {
      color: darkState ? "#ffffff" : "#343a40",
      textShadow: `3px 3px 2px ${
        darkState ? "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)" : "rgba(150, 150, 150, 1)"
      }`
    },
    button: {
      margin: theme.spacing(1)
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    name: ""
  });
  const { name } = state;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(darkState, state);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("darkState", darkState, state);
  }, [darkState]);

  const onChange = ({ target: { value } }, name) => {
    setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, [name]: value }));
  };

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className={className(classes.title, "text-6xl font-bold hp")}>
        Page
        <span className="text-primary">1</span>
      </h1>

      <div
        style={{
          width: "50%",
          minHeight: "600px"
        }}
      >
        <div style={{ paddingBottom: 15 }}>
          <TextField
            fullWidth
            id="outlined-basic"
            label={"Name"}
            variant="outlined"
            size="small"
            value={name}
            onChange={(value) => onChange(value, "name")}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask why you are using the useEffect hook mulitple times?

Comment: @Ruben: Are you referring inside the Page1.js component?

Comment: Is the title accurate? You are updating prop and hence the component is rerendering. State value is lost. You will have to store outside the component either in parent or in storage.

Comment: @tushar: What would you recommend?
Then in the case of opening and closing the drawer, when it is in resized mode, the darkState prop is not updated, so the component shouldn't render, right?